# Could not parse as expression defining a DataTable in Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, thymeleaf

I have a basic SpringBoot 2.0.4.RELEASE app. using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

I have this definition of a datatable in a template

```
    <script th:inline="javascript">
            /*<![CDATA[*/ 

        $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';

            var ajaxUrl = /*[[@{${ajaxUrl}}]]*/ "";

                var table = $('#smsEventTable').DataTable( {
                    order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                    select: true,
                    bLengthChange: false,
                    stateSave: true,
                    pageLength: 20,
                    ajax: ajaxUrl, 
                       "columns": [
                           { data: 'id' },
                           { data: 'smsId' },
                           { data: 'companyName' },
                           { data: 'description' },
                           { data: 'battery', className: 'col_battery' },
                           { data: 'dateTime' },
                           { data: 'signal' },           
                           { data: 'data' },
                           { data: 'alarm' }
                       ] 
                });

            /*]]>*/
</script>
```

But the first time I load the page and there is no data I got this error:

```
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: " 0, "desc" " (template: "/sms/smsList" - line 273, col 12)
```

Comment: This is JavaScript code. Do you have this in a <script></script> node?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem here is this expression: `order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],`.  Because that expression has double brackets (`[[` and `]]`), Thymeleaf is trying to evaluate it as an [inline expression](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining).  The simplest way to fix this is to format it differently by break up the brackets:

```
order: [ [0, "desc"] ],
```

or

```
order: [
    [0, "desc"]
],
```

You could also break up your JavaScript into two blocks (disabling inlining in the second one) like this:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var ajaxUrl = /*[[@{${ajaxUrl}}]]*/ "";
</script>

<script th:inline="none">
/*<![CDATA[*/ 
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';

    var table = $('#smsEventTable').DataTable({
        order: [[0, "desc"]],
        select: true,
        bLengthChange: false,
        stateSave: true,
        pageLength: 20,
        ajax: ajaxUrl, 
           "columns": [
               {data: 'id'},
               {data: 'smsId'},
               {data: 'companyName'},
               {data: 'description'},
               {data: 'battery', className: 'col_battery'},
               {data: 'dateTime'},
               {data: 'signal'},           
               {data: 'data'},
               {data: 'alarm'}
           ] 
    });
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Break the square brackets as follows,

```
order: [
   [0, "desc"]
],
```